# Create and query a temporary table with criteria from another temporary table

Tags: sql, oracle, temp-tables

I created two temporary tables and I want to make a query resulting in

```
Adam Eats Rasins     Fork Life
Dan  Eats Hotpockets At   Home
```

Below are the code I used to generate the two temporary tables and the query I ran which fetched all three rows.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TABI (AAA CHAR(20), AAB CHAR(20), AAC CHAR(20), 
AAD CHAR(20), AAE CHAR(20));

INSERT INTO TABI VALUES('Tim','Eats','Corn','Fork','Work');
INSERT INTO TABI VALUES('Adam','Eats','Rasins','Fork','Life');
INSERT INTO TABI VALUES('Dan','Eats','Hotpockets','At','Home');

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE CRIT (CRIV CHAR(4));

INSERT INTO CRIT VALUES('CORN');

SELECT TABI.*
FROM TABI, CRIT
WHERE UPPER(TABI.AAC) NOT LIKE CRIT.CRIV;
```

My problem right now is that it's fetching all three rows when I want it to fetch two rows with Adam and Dan, but not Tim. Table one has five columns and table two has only one column.

Is it my NOT LIKE? I can use the code below and I will successfully only produce one row with Tim.

```
SELECT TABI.*
FROM TABI, CRIT
WHERE UPPER(TABI.AAC) = CRIT.CRIV;
```

Comment: What do you expect if CRIT is empty? No rows or all the rows in TABI?

Comment: If the CRIT table is empty, then it should produce all rows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

!= could be used.
Also you can use similar syntax:

```
SELECT TABI.*
FROM TABI, CRIT
WHERE UPPER(TABI.AAC) <> CRIT.CRIV;
```

Or other variant:

```
SELECT TABI.*
FROM TABI t
LEFT JOIN CRIT c ON (UPPER(t.AAC) = c.CRIV)
WHERE c.CRIV IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

use Not In Clause:

```
SELECT TABI.*
FROM TABI, CRIT
WHERE UPPER(TABI.AAC) Not IN( CRIT.CRIV);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to extract the rows from `TABI` for which "not exists" a matching row in `CRIT`; that is:

```
SELECT TABI.*
FROM TABI
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM CRIT
                  WHERE UPPER(TABI.AAC) = CRIT.CRIV
                 )
```